# Bad key/Key does not exist exception in RSA

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I am writing a program to encrypt and decrypt using the private and public keys generated from this website - [rsa_key_generation](http://www.mobilefish.com/services/rsa_key_generation/rsa_key_generation.php)

I set the keysize to 512 and base64. And here is my code.

```
class Program
{
    private static RSACryptoServiceProvider _rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
    static string p = "DYy2r60MEQJR2gyYmkuEQp7F8a2D=rOjd60tOR=FF8Z";
    static string q = "8_oSxChqnGrGHTW0gt4CggZ2pOQZI8SR1uFWZIn4yRr";
    static string mod = "1vg1y6ZmYtGILIVgbgezzwUcnnmSRp1hwQuxRTIiQNbrz=fi4myRn7KwJyG2aKDEG69pseLMqetYYCTQUKCyr=";
    static string exp = "G01";
    static string d = "1khYtBuSMaCtYf7ECrIV6=b36bBGwxUvzTUrwQvRJNf70h0sFNnxBARiNrZdb8DWJsgjQEKhBUcWOD4aII1xv1";
    static string dP = "6VTNXCrpUJP_tbJbzCA_s38haB_T3IEGWYC_1pCpha=";
    static string dQ = "3=p7GQ9v613wldg8eSEdxNCvRfeIfBvhomPdigmMwhP";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string encryptedPIN = RSAEncrypt("1234");
        Console.WriteLine("Encrypted Text Recieved: " + encryptedPIN);
        string decryptedPIN = RSADecrypt(encryptedPIN);
        Console.WriteLine("\nDecrypted Text Recieved: " + decryptedPIN);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static string RSAEncrypt(string plainText)
    {
        AssingParams();

        RSAParameters rsaParam = new RSAParameters();

        rsaParam.Modulus = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(mod);
        rsaParam.Exponent = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(exp);            

        _rsaProvider.ImportParameters(rsaParam);

        byte[] plainBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
        byte[] cipherBytes = _rsaProvider.Encrypt(plainBytes, false);
        return Convert.ToBase64String(cipherBytes);
    }

    public static string RSADecrypt(string cipherText)
    {
        AssingParams();
        byte[] cipherBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
        RSAParameters rsaParam = new RSAParameters();

        rsaParam.Modulus = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(mod);
        rsaParam.D = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(d);
        rsaParam.Exponent = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(exp);
        rsaParam.Q = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(q);
        rsaParam.DP = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dP);
        rsaParam.DQ = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dQ);

        _rsaProvider.ImportParameters(rsaParam);

        byte[] plainText = _rsaProvider.Decrypt(cipherBytes, false);
        return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainText);
    }

    public static void AssingParams()
    {
        const int PROVIDER_RSA_FULL = 1;
        const string CONTAINER_NAME = "RSAContainer";
        CspParameters cspParams;
        cspParams = new CspParameters(PROVIDER_RSA_FULL);
        cspParams.KeyContainerName = CONTAINER_NAME;
        cspParams.Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseMachineKeyStore;
        _rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(1024, cspParams);
    }       
}
```

The variables declared as string p, q, mod, exp, d, dP and dQ are copied from the website. While the encryption works fine in decryption I get this error 'Bad Data'. I tried adding modulus to the decryption key then I get the error 'Key does not exist'.

Please help.

Comment: You don't just need `N` and `d`, you need `p`, `q`, `dp`,... as well.

Comment: 1) It is available. `p` and `q` are called `Prime1` and `Prime2` 2) Why are you using a website to generate your RSA keys? `RSACryptoServiceProvider` can generate RSA keys, no need to trust some website.

Comment: Even if I add all these parameters I get the error Key does not exist.

Comment: Post your updated code then. Your current code is totally broken on many levels. Those values aren't UTF-8 encoded. They look similar to Base64, but those `=` in the middle aren't valid either.

Comment: I am using this website because its customer requirement. And I am not able to implement it in C#.

Comment: ok. I will post the whole code here.

Comment: As both NaNa and me wrote, your use of UTF-8 is obviously wrong. You need a weird variant of Base64, since that website doesn't use standard Base64. Or use hex and copy hex values from that website, that's probably easier.

Comment: And you should tell your customer that it's *really* dumb to use keys generated by that website. That website is for demo purposes and not secure. If an attacker who knows you used it and your browser isn't Opera they can simply break your RSA keys, no matter how large.

Comment: BTW 512 bits is far too small for security. It costs less than 100$ to break one of those. 1024 bits is the minimum of what can be considered secure. But even 1024 is a bit weak, most people recommend 2048 bits. And `Encrypt(plainBytes, false)` uses a broken padding which is vulnerable to padding oracles, so the Vaudenay attack can be used to decrypt your messages. Using `Encrypt(plainBytes, true)` is essential for security.

Comment: You still don't fill in `InverseQ`. And you still use the wrong encoding.

Comment: @CodesInChaos this is a kind of universal base algorithm used on the site. The only sane way is to use hexadecimals on that site.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that it works at all?

How you are able to use `cspParams` *before* it's declared?

I'm not surprised that

```
return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainText);
```

shows errors. `plainText` does not exist in current context.

Do you use variables that are declared outside shown methods? If so, check their visibility.

Comment: I suggest to rethink whole design, too. Why do you invoke static constructor of RSACryptoServiceProvider class? Haven't you notices that this class is overloaded and in fact AssingParams() method is not necessary?

Comment: My code does not even reach till that line. It falls out at 

    byte[] plainText = _rsaProvider.Decrypt(cipherBytes, false);

with error. Key does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the hexadecimal encoding on that site as the returned base 64 encoding quite different from normal base 64 encoding. The bits have shifted and other characters have been used. Either that or you would have to create the decoding algorithm for this specific base 64 yourself (very doable, but you would have to look into the Java Script code). Don't forget to *decode* in your source as you now try to encode the encoded string.